# site_url() is not work properly in codeigniter framework

Tags: codeigniter

The following code does not work properly for the Codeigniter framework...

Its my View:

```
<?php
    echo '<h2>'.$news_item['title'].'</h2>';
    echo $news_item['text']."</br></br>";
?>
<a href="<?php site_url("news"); ?>" > Back to Main </a></br></br>
```

Comment: Did you load URL helper in controller or in autoload? and echo this

$this->load->helper('url');

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have loaded the url_helper in your controller construct method or in the function that calls your view like this `$this->load->helper('url')` and then in your view you should echo the `site_url()`

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url("news"); ?>" > Back to Main </a></br></br>`
```

Comment: I was missing echo/print make sure you combine with site_url()

Answer (score 3):

Did u load url helper

Did u specify the site_url in config file...
->Returns your site URL, as specified in your config file. The index.php file (or whatever you have set as your site index_page in your config file) will be added to the URL, as will any URI segments you pass to the function, and the url_suffix as set in your config file.

If not working try with base_url

Comment: echo the base_url or site_url 
<a href="<?=site_url("news")?>" > Back to Main </a>

Answer (score 0):

Try base url

```
 <a href="<?=base_url("news")?>" > Back to Main </a>
```

base url return's without any further pages

refer also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17079745/7817622