# what is the difference between site_url() and base_url()?

Tags: php, codeigniter

As I have read in some resources, `base_url()` and `site_url()` functions in `Codeigniter` are almost the same, although my version of Codeigniter (2.1.3) does not have a site_url() in its config.php file (in the config directory).

Yet are there differences between them in any way since I have seen site_url() with parameters and never seen base_url() holding none?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
echo base_url(); // http://example.com/website
echo site_url(); // http://example.com/website/index.php
```

if you want a URL access to a resource (such as  css, js, image), use `base_url()`, otherwise, `site_url()` is better.

for a detailed reference Check this both function in CodeIgniter.

```
public function site_url($uri = '')
    {
        if (empty($uri))
        {
            return $this->slash_item('base_url').$this->item('index_page');
        }
        $uri = $this->_uri_string($uri);
        if ($this->item('enable_query_strings') === FALSE)
        {
            $suffix = isset($this->config['url_suffix']) ? $this->config['url_suffix'] : '';
            if ($suffix !== '')
            {
                if (($offset = strpos($uri, '?')) !== FALSE)
                {
                    $uri = substr($uri, 0, $offset).$suffix.substr($uri, $offset);
                }
                else
                {
                    $uri .= $suffix;
                }
            }
            return $this->slash_item('base_url').$this->slash_item('index_page').$uri;
        }
        elseif (strpos($uri, '?') === FALSE)
        {
            $uri = '?'.$uri;
        }
        return $this->slash_item('base_url').$this->item('index_page').$uri;
    }
```

Base URL function.

```
public function base_url($uri = '')
        {
            return $this->slash_item('base_url').ltrim($this->_uri_string($uri), '/');
        }
```

Comment: I guess @sikander's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17079780/248616 should clarify it better

Comment: You may view his answer in the given link in my comment - the bold difference about `index.php` should be highlighted.

Comment: Thanks buddy you save my time.

Answer (score 23):

`site_url`: Returns base_url + index_page + uri_string

`base_url`: Returns base_url + uri_string

See source code of both functions at: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/606fee0e2e0aa6a906db82e77090e91f133d7378/system/core/Config.php

Comment: This is crystal clear and should be the accepted answer to me ^^

Answer (score 14):

#### 1. site_url

The purpose of `site_url` is that your pages become more portable in the event your URL changes.The `site_url` appears with the `index.php` file.

Segments can be optionally passed to the function as a string or an array.

```
echo site_url("news/local/123");
```

it will give: http://ci.com/index.php/news/local/123

you can even pass segments as an array:

```
$segments = array('news', 'local', '123');
echo site_url($segments);
```

#### 2. base_url

`base_url` is without the `index_page` or `url_suffix` being appended.
like `site_url`, you can supply segments as a string or an array.

If you want a URL access to a resource use `base_url` you can supply a string to a file, such as an image or stylesheet else `site_url` is enough.

```
echo base_url("/images/icons/image.png");
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, you can create file `.htaccess` in the CodeIgniter root folder next to its `index.php` file.

just add this code on `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

this code will make the word `index.php` remain unseen.

```
http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/controllersName/
```

will be changed to this

```
http://localhost/CodeIgniter/controllersName/
```

Answer (score 1):

`base_url()` that is commonly used in `Codeigniter` can be used even without the `.php` extension.

`site_url()` which is commonly used in `Wordpress` custom template can be used even when you just call the `post_title` of the blog or the file name with the extension.

Answer (score 1):

site_url() is execute  index.php that why site_url is better as compare to base_url.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add when to use base_url() and the site_url() . Basically one can use site_url() while creating links for controllers whereas base_url() can be used where we need to create urls for the assets like loading a css or js file or some image .

What I always prefer is to use site_url() for creating links to controllers or ajax urls and base_url() for loading assets .