# Ajax post not being hit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter where i put the post backend coding under models/add_subscriber.php
but the code not being hit. Any idea?

```
form.onsubmit = function(event) {
            validate();
            if (!isValid) {
                revalidateOnChange();
                return false;
            }
            var email = $("#signup_email").val();
            dataString = 'email=' + email;
            $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '<?php echo base_url()?>models/add_subscriber.php',
                        data: dataString,
                        success: function(response) {
                            alert(response);
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {

                        }
                    });
               return;

        };
```

Comment: You need to call a _controller_ , not a model. It's controllers that are instantiated upon a server request, and they in turn call a model

Comment: ok.i tried controllers and it didn't got hit too. url: '<?php echo base_url()?>controllers/home/add',

Comment: The URL for the controller is `<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/add;` not the one you specified.

Answer (score 1):

try to figure out step by step,

1. Your request is working check in firebug or chrome developer tool net panel may be javascript error there.
2. hit directly the url see the url is valid view source of the javascript and copy the ajax url and paste it to address bar and see whether your url is valid.
3. if url is ok and ajax is working and the response isn't 404 than check your controller, htaccess etc.

**Suggestion**

if you want a URL access to a resource (such as css, js, image), use `base_url()`, otherwise, `site_url()` is better. [**source**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079711/what-is-the-difference-between-site-url-and-base-url/17079745#17079745)

Answer (score 1):

Create a controller in the "controllers" folder...
Create a file something like this:

```
class your_controller extends CI_Controller {
    function example_function(){
        // PUT HERE YOU CODE that is in the models.addsubscriber.php
    }
}
```

In your code JS script, put this URL:

```
url: '<?php echo base_url()?>your_controller/example_function/'
```