# Difference betwwen CodeIgniter Site Url and base Url

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello What is the difference between SiteUrl() and BaseUrl()
?
In my previous project it is base url but now in my new project it is Siteurl.Why this happens?
Is baseurl() is an outdated one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the difference between site\_url() and base\_url()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079711/what-is-the-difference-between-site-url-and-base-url)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To clear all your doubts you have to read CodeIgniter Manual.[Please Click Here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

***base URL***

> Returns your site base URL, as specified in your config file. Example:
>   echo base_url();
>
> This function returns the same thing as site_url, without the
>   index_page or url_suffix being appended.
>
> Also like site_url, you can supply segments as a string or an array.
>   Here is a string example: echo base_url("blog/post/123");

***site URL***

> Returns your site URL, as specified in your config file. The index.php
>   file (or whatever you have set as your site index_page in your config
>   file) will be added to the URL, as will any URI segments you pass to
>   the function, and the url_suffix as set in your config file.
>
> You are encouraged to use this function any time you need to generate
>   a local URL so that your pages become more portable in the event your
>   URL changes.
>
> Segments can be optionally passed to the function as a string or an
>   array. Here is a string example: echo site_url("news/local/123");
>
> The above example would return something like:
>   http://example.com/index.php/news/local/123
>
> Here is an example of segments passed as an array: $segments =
>   array('news', 'local', '123');
>
> echo site_url($segments);

Answer (score 7):

Base url for Image / script / css  path. 
site url for Address url for accessing the controllers

```
echo base_url(); // http://example.com/path/to/your/ci/install
echo site_url(); // http://example.com/path/to/your/ci/install/index.php
```

You can refer this forum:

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/113974/

Comment: Here is the ref: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: What if I remove index.php with .htaccess? Can I use base_url all times?

Comment: @KumarV, I just want to know what is the best for anchor tag?

Comment: @user9437856, if you want to use CI anchor , then have to use `anchor(uri segments, text, attributes)`. Otherwise you can use plain html `a` tag with `site_url()` in href.

Comment: Thanks, @KumarV, So I am using like this <a href="<?php echo site_url()?>/about.php"></a>. Is it a best practices?

Answer (score 0):

No doubts the answers by kumar_v  and nidheesh are absolutely correct . However , I would like to add when to use base_url() and the site_url() . Basically one can use site_url() while creating links for controllers whereas  base_url() can be used where we need to create urls for  the assets like loading a css or js file or some image .

What I always prefer is to use site_url() for creating links to controllers or ajax urls
and base_url() for loading  assets .