# Trouble to call a view

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have to a controller with name about.php in controller folder. now in view folder i have a view with name about.php. in index.php view i want to call that view with the link but it is not calling i am very new to Codeignitor.

This is my calling code in index.php

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>About/about">About Us</a>
```

This is my controller code about.php in controller folder.

```
class About extends CI_Controller {

    function index(){

        $this->load->view('about');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view should be called `about.php` and be in the `views` folder.

Your controller is then calling this view (correctly) called `about`.

Therefore a correct link to this view would be the following:

```
<a href="<?= site_url('about'); ?>">About Us</a>
```

You can read about the differences between `base_url` and `site_url` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764803/difference-betwwen-codeigniter-site-url-and-base-url).

Comment: thank yor sir it is working fine but my link is like this "http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/about"  can we remove .php or index.php from this link

Comment: Yes, you can do this with a simple change to your .htaccess file. This is in the CodeIgniter documentation: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Comment: sir what is index.php here can your explain

Comment: index.php is the file index.php. When you go to index.php/about, you're really just going to index.php - the script then loads the controller 'about' and displays it. By adding a few lines to .htaccess you can make it appear that there is no index.php file, but essentially going to /about will still go to index.php. I would advise reading the CodeIgniter documentation for more information

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/about">About Us</a>
```

Comment: what is index.php here

Comment: By default, the index.php file will be included in your URLs. You can easily remove this file by using a .htaccess file with some simple rules.