# Unable to upload file to directory

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to create a folder and then upload a file to the folder. I am receiving the error message:

```
The upload path does not appear to be valid.
```

Here is my folder structure:

```
/System
/Application
/users
     /johndoe
         /products
              /1
              /2
```

Here is how I am creating the folder:

```
$productpath = site_url('users/'.$this->session->userdata('username').'/products/'.$item_id);

        mkdir($productpath,777,true);
```

So I add the following to my script to try to debug:

```
var_dump(is_writable(site_url('users')));
var_dump(is_dir(site_url('users')));
```

Both of those return false. If I echo `$productpath`:

```
echo "Here is the product path: ".$productpath;

the upload path is: http://localhost:8888/gameday/users/jackie109/products/49
```

- Why is /users not a directory?
- I assume `is_writeable` returns false because it cannot be written because it is not a directory
- Am I linking to my path right? Is `site_url` the right thing to use here?

Comment: because it's `/users`, not `users`. Without the `/`. you're dealing with a relative path,starting from wherever this script's current working directory is (e.g. `cwd()`. e.g. if the script is `/foo/bar/script.php`, then `is_dir('users')` will probably be testing `/foo/bar/users`.

Comment: I think @fstephen07 may be lost on what `site_url()` does. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079711/what-is-the-difference-between-site-url-and-base-url

Comment: A URL is not a file path.

Comment: It should be something more along the lines of: 

$user = $this->session->userdata('username');
mkdir("/users/".$user."/products/".$item_id, 0777, true);

Comment: Yes, that fixed it. Thanks. If someone can mark that an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of site_url you can use **base_url**. You should maintain upload files outside the applications directory.

ie., siterootdir/uploads/users

and should not siterootdir/applications/uploads/users