# url in jquery ajax post in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to set jQuery Ajax post URL.But it is not working as I want. I searched a lot and I got many solution.But none of them indicate my problem.
I set the base URL in `var baseurl = "<?php print base_url(); ?>";` in js file and use it in `$.ajax url` concatenating it.It gives me

```
Disallowed Key Characters.php_print_base_url();_?>welcome/add_tag
```

I think the `var baseurl` is not working.

**html**

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/my_js.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="add_tag" placeholder="add more tags"/>
```

**js**

```
var baseurl = "<?php print base_url(); ?>";
$('#add_tag').on('keyup paste', function () {
            tag_text=$(this).val();
            if(tag_text==='')
              return;
            $.ajax(
            {
             type: "POST",
             url: baseurl+"welcome/add_tag",
             data: {tag_textTo:tag_text},
             success: function(data){
             $('.tags_found').html(data);
            }
        });
        });
```

**CI_Controller**

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
        public function add_tag() 
        {
            $tag_text=$this->input->post('tag_textTo');
            echo $tag_text;
        }
}
```

How to make it work?thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried ? `var baseurl = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";` ? and where does your url points in the console (view-source) ?

Comment: yes. but give same result

Comment: What does the  `console.log(baseurl)` give ?

Comment: it gives <?php print base_url(); ?>

Comment: You tried the anyone of the option in my answer ?

Comment: try :     
    
     var baseurl = <?php echo json_encode(base_url()); ?>;

Comment: @crc442 also give same result

Comment: Oh! Did you try without the quotes?

Comment: Can you able to figure out what this is ? `<script>
    var baseurl = "<?php echo 'google.com';?>"
    console.log(baseurl);
</script>`

Comment: @crc442 when i am going to write without quotes it shows error.red underline

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen yes the baseurl variable should contain google.com but it has <?php echo 'google.com';?>. why ? i loaded the url helper properly

Comment: Ahh,, Have you loaded the url helper globally i.e., in the autoload ??

Comment: yes it is in autoload

Comment: Have you tried `var baseurl = "<?php print base_url(); ?>"; console.log(baseurl)` ?

Comment: ah, ok in php just `echo base_url();`

Comment: try like this ,url: "<?php echo site_url('welcome/add_tag');?>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**problem found**

I am using an *external* js file for ajax call.
Now I know codeIgniter `url` helper does not recognize my `baseurl` variable in external js file.
That is line
`var baseurl = "<?php print base_url(); ?>";`in external file.

The answer given by @Sulthan Allaudeen and @saravanan n (thanks to them)all are working when I declare the `baseurl var`

> in my php view file internally.

**view file**

```
<script type="text/javascript">var baseurl = "<?php print base_url(); ?>";</script>
```

The remaining `js` code can be stay on external file.

```
$('#add_tag').on('keyup paste', function () {
            tag_text=$(this).val();
            if(tag_text==='')
              return;
            $.ajax(
            {
             type: "POST",
             url: baseurl+"welcome/add_tag",
             data: {tag_textTo:tag_text},
             success: function(data){
             $('.tags_found').html(data);
            }
        });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the `baseurl` like this

```
var baseurl = '<?=base_url()?>';
```

or

```
var baseurl = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
```

And inside the jquery ajax call

```
  url: baseurl+"welcome/add_tag",
```

Else totally

```
url: <?php echo base_url();?>"welcome/add_tag",
```

**Note :**

Don't forget to load the `url` helper

Answer (score 0):

Try with [site_url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079711/what-is-the-difference-between-site-url-and-base-url)

```
url: "<?php echo site_url('welcome/add_tag');?>"
```