# Codeigniter 404 error not found assets folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have problem with my codeiginiter project. 
I use xamp and I have my project folder in htdocs. 
To see my project i must type http://localhost/myproject/
I want to add some assets to project and I crete folder to do that.

```
- htdocs
-- myproject 
---- application
-----controllers
-----models  
----- views
----- assets // folder with js, css ect
---- system
---- index.php
----  .htaccess
```

Now when I want to load script in specyfic view, like this

```
 <script src="../assets/js/app.js"></script>
```

I got error 404 and in console

```
GET http://localhost/assets/app.js
```

As you can see CodeIgniter want to download assets from the wrong place.

My htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: when you enter http://localhost/myproject/asstest/app.js in your browser, can you see file or you seeing 404 page ?

Comment: @Roboticsexpert - asstest? Lol ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrong place to have your assets folder. Your assets folder should be in the main directory and not your application directory. As the htaccess file in application blocks css and images etc

Place your assets

```
application
assets
assets > css
assets > images
assets > js
index.php
.htaccess <-- Main directory htaccess file
```

Then autoload the url helper http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

And then you would be able to use `<?php echo base_url('assets/js/app.js');?>` you don't have to autoload the url helper but it would save you time other wise you will have to load it in each controller you need it in.

Answer (score 1):

codeigniter has some function for this purpose like : `base_url() or site_url()`

those function have some difference that you can see it in :

[what is the difference between site_url() and base_url()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079711/what-is-the-difference-between-site-url-and-base-url)

you can use this for your script src :

```
<?php
echo '<script src="'.base_url('assets/js/app.js').'"></script>';
?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I was not at home. It's work but I must put assets folder upper, next to application, system etc.

Comment: best path for assets is next to index.php @hheroinMe

Answer (score 0):

Try this once. This is better way to access your scripts

```
<script src="<?php echo site_url('assets/js/app.js'); ?>"></script>
```

Comment: you should use base_url ...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079711/what-is-the-difference-between-site-url-and-base-url

Comment: site_url is better for inside the controller and base url good for using links on views.