# Pagination in Codeigniter creating strange links

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am doing a Pagination system in Codeigniter and something is not working properly.

I have a search that gives 5 results in total.

If I put 1 item per page it creates the pagination with the links as

```
example.com/suppliers/   Page 1
example.com/suppliers/1   Page 2
example.com/suppliers/2   Page 3
example.com/suppliers/3   Page 4
example.com/suppliers/4   Page 5
```

which is correct

But if I put 2 items per page tt appears as

```
example.com/suppliers/   Page 1
example.com/suppliers/2   Page 2
example.com/suppliers/4   Page 3
```

And if I put 3 items per page it appears as

```
example.com/suppliers/   Page 1
example.com/suppliers/3   Page 2
```

So it is jumping pages in an order of magnitude equivalent to the results per page.

This is the code used to generate the pagination:

```
//Create the pagination links
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'/suppliers';
$config['total_rows'] = $this->data['count_suppliers'];
$config['per_page'] = RESULTS_IN_SEARCH;    
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['prev_link'] = '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="next">';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['next_link'] = '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close']='</li>';

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

$this->data['pagination']=$this->pagination->create_links();
```

In the image attached you can see the results.

[Pagination problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6v5CW.png)

SOLVED: Adding $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE; to the pagination configuration and when doing the query to the database substract 1 so the Page 1 searches for LIMIT 0, 3 instead of  LIMIT 3,3

Comment: you can try `$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;`

Comment: I've added your suggestion and then when actually doing the query to the database substract 1 to the page number and it worked. It isn't the most stylish but it works. Thanks. Put it as an answer and I will vote.

Comment: You can edit my answer I'm very bad know English. I understand but can't correct write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding in your array configuration key `$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE` for get numbers page and don't get start numbers item in url.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is from `base_url()`. And you can use `site_url()` instead of `base_url();` so please see the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079711/what-is-the-difference-between-site-url-and-base-url).

**Base_url** - This is the full URL to the controller class/function containing your pagination. In the example above, it is pointing to a controller called “Test” and a function called “page”. Keep in mind that you can [re-route your URI](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html) if you need a different structure.

```
$this->load->library('pagination');

$config['base_url'] = base_url().'/suppliers';
$config['total_rows'] = 200;
$config['per_page'] = 20;

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

And please read more about pagination [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html#customizing-the-pagination).

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the controller function for page number as 0 if

```
public function show_entries($page = 0) {          
    ----
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $per_page=2; //what ever
    $config["per_page"] = $per_page;
    -----
}
```

Comment: I already have the page at the top set up that way and the per_page is being retrieved from a constant

Comment: what your aim with this pagination ?

Comment: Get the results in different pages instead of showing 50 suppliers in one page.

Comment: $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE; use this

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code:-

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url('suppliers/' . $id);
```

If not working then add below code also:-

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;
$page = ($this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment'])) ? $this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment']) : 0;
$data['topics_array'] = $this->forum->get_topics($id, $config['per_page'], $page);
$data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Refer this [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/) also.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, codeigniter will build the links with the current page on top of the one that will add for each link.