# CodeIgniter base_url() issue in anchor tag

Tags: php, codeigniter, base-url

I want to load my home page(base_url) when I click on my logo.

**Base url** - (`http://localhost:8888/adminpanel/`)
When I use base_url() function inside the anchor tag like `<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>"` , It taking me to (`http://localhost:8888/adminpanel/index.html`).

Actually I couldn't find this index.html anywhere in my **adminpanel** folder.

So friends please help me to find a solution for this. Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: have you added $this->load->helper('url'); in the controller  ?

Comment: have you chaged  your .htaccess file ??

Comment: I would autoload the url helper in autoload.php http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: Also have a look here `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` and see whats set on config.php

Comment: @TejasMehta yes i have added that already.

Comment: @TejasMehta this is my .htaccess file `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] `

Comment: okay then is it only comes with the anchor tag ?? better to show your code  here @Shihas

Comment: @wolfgang1983 i have autoload url helper and config.php file  is like this `$config['index.php'] = '';`

Comment: @Shihas show us your base url

Comment: @TejasMehta `<a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo base_url('blog'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/ro.jpg')?>" class="img-responsive" alt="" title=""></a>`

Comment: @Spartan `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8888/adminpanel/';`

Comment: @TejasMehta for the img tag my base_url() function works fine. **blog** is my controller

Comment: show `adminpanel` structure as well

Comment: @Spartan structure means?

Comment: add routes page codes

Comment: @Spartan I'm a newbie. Can u help me to write routes. **Blog** is my controller and in that index function is calling the view (`main.php`).

Comment: What is set in `APPPATH.'config/config.php'` on line 69?

Comment: You might be able to find some suitable htaccess for your codeiginter project here https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

okay i got it can you please try  with

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo base_url();?>blog"><img src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/img/ro.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" title=""></a>
```

dont write your url inside the function
just try with this

Comment: You can also remove "/" if you already got in the base_url() function

Comment: can you help me in routing.. Blog is my controller and in that index function is calling the view `(main.php)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go to your homepage the you can use `<?php echo site_url()?>`
base_url in simple words used for getting base path necessary for css or images

if your hompage is http://www.example.com you can have `<?php echo site_url()?>`

and if you want to go to http://www.example.com/index.php/dashboard you can have `<?php echo site_url('dashboard'); ?>`
where in config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

give a try to the above things.

More description regarding site_url and base_url can be found here
[what is the difference between site_url() and base_url()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079711/what-is-the-difference-between-site-url-and-base-url)

Answer (score 0):

In config.php set following:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/'; // Set your Home URL
```

If you are using mod_rewrite than change following..

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```