# error on ajax while using in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Ajax is not working while using in CodeIgniter. The alert message inside the script is working well but the controller function is not getting the call to perform.

**View part**

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <a class="buttons" onclick="updateExpress(<?php echo $lp->User_Id; ?>)" id="<?php echo $lp->User_Id; ?>" href="javascript:;">
     <span class="button-icon"><i class="far fa-heart"></i>
     </span>Express your interest</a>
</div>
```

script added in the view part is:

```
<script>
   function updateExpress(partnerId){\
      $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/Home/add_express"+partnerId
                });
        alert("Expressed interest at Profile ID M"+partnerId);
     }
</script>
```

The **controller** part is mentioned below:

```
public function add_express()
    {
        $partnerExp=$this->uri->segment(3);
        $user=$_SESSION['userID'];
        $datetoday=date("d-m-Y");
        $data=array(
            'NotificationTo' => $partnerExp,
            'NotificationFrom' => $user,
            'Notification_Id' => '6',
            'date' => $datetoday,
            'Is_read' => '0'
        );

        $data['addresult']=$this->action_data->add_express($data);
    }
```

This function is working while calling this controller function separately. But when it is trying to call using ajax it doesn't work.

Comment: Missing `/` ? Change -  `add_express"+partnerId -` to -`add_express/"+partnerId`

Comment: You may wanna use site_url() there rather than base_url() so you won't have to type index.php at the same time. >> [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079711/what-is-the-difference-between-site-url-and-base-url) <<

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was searching for this error this whole day... thank you so much. It exactly works now... @Mr.Blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing ‘/‘ in the url.

```
add_express”+partnerId
```

To

```
add_express/“+partnerId
```