# How to use sites_url in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, wordpress, codeigniter

I am facing this issue. When I try to access my test_product/import.php in my view, I will have this problem.

> An Error Was Encountered  The action you have requested is not
>   allowed.

my import.php is in /view/test_product/import.php. I am opening it via my all.php in /view/test_product/all.php

Below is my code for all.php

```
<form id="submit_form" action="<?php echo site_url("Test_product/import");?>" method="post">
<p align="right"><button name="import" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submiting" data-loading-text="Adding ... <span class='fa fa-fw fa-spinner'></span>" form="submit_form">Import </button></p>
```

It is all under the same directory /view/test_product/. The purposes of this is to access to my other page import.php .

Comment: You should have to load url_helper in your controller construct method or in the function that calls your view like this $this->load->helper('url').

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623050/site-url-is-not-work-properly-in-codeigniter-framework

Comment: I have try calling that but it still gave the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said your import.php is in views then it is classed as a view file. you can not access a view file direct from site_url. You will need to create a controller to in to be able to access views

```
application > controllers > test_product > Import.php
```

Controller For Import.php

```
<?php

class Import extends CI_Controller {

public function index() {
   // Form submit info goes here.
   $this->load->view('import_view');
}

}
```

Then you can use.

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url("test_product/import");?>"  method="post">
```

[How to use URL Helpers](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Form [Helper](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Form Validation [Library](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

Answer (score 1):

This error is not about "site_url". it's related to Codeigniter CSRF protection.
In order to fix it you should either:

- Use the the form_open() and form_close() helper functions instead of using plain HTML for creating forms. When you use the helper function "csrf token" will be automatically inserted as a hidden field in the form.

or

- If you can't use form_open() or form_close() you can get the CSRF token name and value using

  $this->security->get_csrf_hash();

  $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();

  and send them manually by adding the token as a hidden input field in the form.

  `<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();  ?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>">`

or

- turn off the CSRF protection, which is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

you are using double quotes inside double quotes.

Try
 `"<?php echo site_url('Test_product/import');?>"` 
if not loaded url_helper .try
if you want to autoload URL

```
file location :application/config/autoload.php
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

if want to load per need :

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

suggestion
 it's better to autoload url_helper ,because we need it everywhere.
if you want to access a resource such as css, js, image, use `base_url()`, otherwise, `site_url()`.

Comment: I tried putting in it in my controller class but it doesn't work

Comment: i change my answer,check it

Comment: same problem. An Error Was Encountered

The action you have requested is not allowed.

Comment: did you remove double quote from inside of you site_url() ?

Comment: yeah this is my code "<?php echo site_url('Test_product/import');?>" after edited